# Can not print child properties of mongodb document with nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, children

I have a list of user's documents in mongodb which is carrying fields like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57fb60caf380e20df0d59f4d"),
    "signupFp" : "a47d436a33edb44dfd2c45d6eb5574bd",
    "signupIp" : "127.0.0.1",
    "password" : "d38c2a8589965d869c79ce77e4dc871e",
    "email" : "someemail@gmail.com",
    "createTime" : ISODate("2016-10-10T09:35:06.386Z"),
    "isAdmin" : false,
    "isActive" : true,
    "account" : [ 
        {
            "port" : 5001,
            "server" : "harish server"
        }, 
        {
            "port" : 7001,
            "server" : "harish server"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "sendEmailTime" : ISODate("2016-10-10T09:35:06.405Z"),
    "activeKey" : "61ce67b47ee15547878404d9b5bebab7",
    "lastLogin" : ISODate("2016-10-12T07:51:53.059Z"),
    "expireTime" : ISODate("2016-10-25T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I am fetching all the user's document using nodejs with the following code:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
User.find({}).exec(function(err, data){
    if(err){
        return;
    }
data.forEach(function(user){


       if(user.expireTime < new Date()){
           console.log(user.lastLogin); //prints the last login date
           console.log(user.account); //outputs []
           console.log(user.account.port); //outputs undefined

       }
  }
}
```

and further i need value of child nodes i.e account.port and account.server but when i console.log its giving me blank array [] or undefined to console.log a specific child key

[image: child property empty mongodb]

How do i get the account.port and account.server values

Comment: Can you update your question to include the schema definition for `User` model? Perhaps you have an embedded reference to another model, say `Account`?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified var User = mongoose.model('User'); you don't need to do it in the logs anymore (user.lastLogin),(user.account),(user.account.port) just omit the user from all of them, should work.

```
(lastLogin)
(account)
(account.port)
```

Comment: not worked, i have omit user from each print. It says lastLogin, account not defined

Comment: oh my mistake the user list is printing only that document which are carrying no account nodes